# Embedded Futures are making code unreadable. Is there a way to improve the code

Tags: scala

In the following code, `signInUser` should return `Future[Result]`. My problem is that the function uses `Future` within `Future` and to avoid returning `Future[Future[..]]`, I have to use combination of `map` and `flatMap`. This has made the code unreadable and also difficult to debug. At the moment, this function isn't compiling. How could I improve this code? I tried using `for` but I am not able to write the logic using `for`.

```
def signInUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async{ implicit request => {
    println(s"signupUser action called with request ${utilities.printPlayHttpRequest(request)}")
    val body: AnyContent = request.body
    val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson

    jsonBody match {
      case Some(json) => {
        val readableString: String = Json.prettyPrint(json)
        println(s"received Json ${readableString}")
        val userSignin: Option[UserSignin] = json.asOpt[UserSignin] //check if json conforms with UserProfile structure

        userSignin match {
          case Some(signinInfo) => { //format of JSON is correct

            //Get signin info from JSON (email and password)
            val credentials: Credentials = Credentials(signinInfo.signinInfo.email, signinInfo.signinInfo.password) //TODOM  need to check that password is not empty

            // get the signin validated using the credentialsProvider. credentialsProvider has reference of PasswordRepository. It will use
            //PasswordRepository's to validate the credentials
            //not sure which function of passwordRepository will beused to do so
            //TODOM - is this the correct place to declare these. Should these be in say UserRepository or at the beginning of the controller?

            //TODOM - test case for correct,  incorrect and empty password
            val authInfoRepository = new DelegableAuthInfoRepository(userRepo.passwordRepo)
            val passwordHasherRegistory = new PasswordHasherRegistry(userRepo.passwordHasher)
            val credentialsProvider = new CredentialsProvider(authInfoRepository, passwordHasherRegistory)

            //authenticate method will call PasswordRepository's find method to look for the user
            //flatMap returns the result of its {} as Future
            credentialsProvider.authenticate(credentials).flatMap { loginInfo => { //authenticate could find the loginInfo for the matching ID and password and has returned user's login information
              //get User profile for this login Info
              val userOptionFuture: Future[Option[User]] = silhouette.env.identityService.retrieve(loginInfo) //this is call to instance of fUserService class created in AppLoader??
              userOptionFuture.map { userOption:Option[User] =>
                userOption match {
                    case Some(user) if !user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.confirmed => {
                      println("found user but registration isn't complete",user)
                      Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("registration not complete")))//map will return Future{Ok}, flatMap will flatten it to Ok and then return its own Future{Ok}
                    }
                    case Some(user) => { //this should also return Ok. So any map inside it should be flattened
                      println("found user",user)
                      /*
                      In AppLoader, while creating the Silhouette Environment, an authenticator service was also created.
                      The authenticator service is responsible for creating the CookieAuthenticator. The work flow is
                      1) create CookieAuthenticator
                      2) Initialise it
                      3) embed the Cookie in Result (because we are using Cookie Authenticator)
                       */

                      //create an authenticator
                      val cookieAuthenticatorFuture:Future[CookieAuthenticator] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.create(loginInfo)

                      cookieAuthenticatorFuture.flatMap(cookieAuthenticator => { //if authenticator created successfully then init it.
                        val cookieFuture:Future[Cookie] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.init(cookieAuthenticator)
                        cookieFuture.map(cookie => {
                          //embed the cookie in Result. embed results AuthenticatorResult which extends Play's Result.
                          silhouette.env.authenticatorService.embed(cookie,Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("found user"))))
                        })
                        .recover { case x => {
                            println("Future failed in signInUser. In recover. Returning Internal Server Error"+x)
                            InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error"))) }
                        }

                      })
                      .recover { case x => {
                          println("Future failed in signInUser. In recover. Returning Internal Server Error"+x)
                          InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error"))) }
                        }
                      //Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("found user")))
                    }
                    //TODOM - think of a design such that an error code could point to the location of the code which send the error!
                    case None => Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid user though loginInfo was found!")))
                  }
                }
                .recover { case x => {
                  println("Future failed in signInUser. In recover. Returning Internal Server Error"+x)
                  InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error"))) }
                }
              }
            }
            .recover { case x => {
                println("Future failed in signInUser. In recover. Returning Internal Server Error"+x)
                InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error"))) }
            }
          }
          case None => { //No signin info found
            Future {
              Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid user. No Login info found")))
            }
          }
        }
      }
      //got json in message body.
      case None => { //NO JSON Body
          Future {  Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid Body Type. Need Json"))) }/*TODOM - Standardise error messages. Use as constants*/
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That seems way too far from being an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It doesn't look even remotely minimal. It's nowhere close to compiling because it has thousand irrelevant dependencies. Please try to reduce the amount of code until you can isolate the exact problem. You could at least start by making the indentation consistent, and making sure that the code is not wider than 80 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things you can do:

Let the framework validate the body:

```
silhouette.UserAwareAction.async (parse.json[User]) {implicit r =>
... // r.body will now be of type `User`
```

The framework will send a 400 bad request for invalid user json.

Let the framework handle errors: Remove the `recover`, the framework will send a 500 internal server error and log the exception.

User a for-comprehension, it's easier to read and should replace most calls to map/flatten/flatMap.

Move repositories to injected parameters on the controller constructor.